# Do not run linter and prettier while compiling

Tags: javascript, eslint, prettier

I have a personal project with some friends where we have configured eslint and prettier and they are running like "automatically" when project is compiling. So, while I am working on my tasks and project is running, if I have a prettier error some where, or a linter error (an import or variable I typed but I am not using yet), project will directly FAIL and won't compile anymore....
Example:

[image]

This is super SUPER annoying. Those things are things that shouldn't break the app, I should be able to keep working and seeing the app compiled.

In my previous and current company we had and have prettier and/or eslint in the projects but they didnt run automatically, they just run when you type the commands on the terminal, or when commiting, husky ran the commands for you. Configuration is different and I tried to copy it but it never worked.

I have been trying for days googling this but nothing is working...

I want prettier and eslint to inform me the errors only when I write the commands by myself on the terminal (npm run lint and npm run format), but it looks like they are being ran by theirselves everytime project compiles...

This is the package.json:

```
{
    "name": "gamma-project",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
        "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
        "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
        "@types/react": "^16.9.53",
        "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
        "firebase": "8.0.2",
        "i18next": "^19.9.0",
        "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.0.1",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "react": "^17.0.1",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
        "react-i18next": "^11.8.8",
        "react-phone-input-2": "^2.13.9",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
        "react-use-gesture": "^9.1.3",
        "react-verification-code-input": "^1.2.9",
        "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
        "typescript": "^4.1.3",
        "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "lint": "eslint . --fix ",
        "format": "prettier --write \"./**/*.{ts,tsx}\" --config ./.prettierrc"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.6",
        "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.7",
        "@types/webpack-env": "^1.16.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.11.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.11.1",
        "eslint": "^7.17.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
        "husky": ">=4",
        "lint-staged": ">=10",
        "prettier": "^2.2.1"
    }
}
```

.prettierrc:

```
{
    "semi": true,
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "printWidth": 100,
    "singleQuote": false,
    "jsxSingleQuote": false,
    "trailingComma": "none",
    "jsxBracketSameLine": true,
    "endOfLine": "auto"
}
```

.eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
    parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    root: true, // Make sure eslint picks up the config at the root of the directory
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 2020, // Use the latest ecmascript standard
        sourceType: "module", // Allows using import/export statements
        ecmaFeatures: {
            jsx: true // Enable JSX since we're using React
        }
    },
    settings: {
        react: {
            version: "detect" // Automatically detect the react version
        }
    },
    env: {
        browser: true, // Enables browser globals like window and document
        amd: true, // Enables require() and define() as global variables as per the amd spec.
        node: true // Enables Node.js global variables and Node.js scoping.
    },
    extends: [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "prettier/@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    plugins: ["@typescript-eslint"],
    rules: {
        "react/jsx-sort-props": 2,
        "no-console": 2,
        "prettier/prettier": ["error", {}, { usePrettierrc: true }], // Use our .prettierrc file as source
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": ["error"],
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": ["error"],
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["error"],
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": [
            "error",
            {
                allowExpressions: false,
                allowTypedFunctionExpressions: true,
                allowHigherOrderFunctions: true,
                allowDirectConstAssertionInArrowFunctions: true,
                allowConciseArrowFunctionExpressionsStartingWithVoid: true
            }
        ],
        "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": [
            "error",
            {
                selector: "interface",
                format: ["PascalCase"],
                custom: {
                    regex: "^I[A-Z]",
                    match: true
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

I am praying to God someone in Stack Overflow to know exactly how to configure this to not do that, cause it really annoys me to the point that I close vcode and don't code anymore hahah.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want eslint to break your project, just rename the errors as warnings. The way you do this is to set `emitWarning: true`:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: '...',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        options: {
          emitWarning: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

If that doesn't work out, try this plug-in, which converts all eslint errors to warnings: https://github.com/bfanger/eslint-plugin-only-warn.

Comment: Hi Chris! First of all thank you very much for answering!! Before we did try to configure all the rules with a 1 (warn) instead of 2 (error) BUT if you do that, then husky allows you to commit files with the warnings, and that would miss the point of doing all this. We want to prevent members of the team to commit files that are not following the rules..

I am sure there is a way to configure this, cause I worked on projects where linter didnt run automatically while compiling, I just can't find how to do that in this project  :(